# jQuery activate on DropDownList/SELECT item changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jQuery code that filters out a list of links on the page. At present the filtering is fired when a link with a blind href is clicked. The id of the link is taken to determine which content remains visible on the page. EG:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    //when a link in the filters div is clicked...
    $('#filters a').click(function (e) {

        //prevent the default behaviour of the link
        e.preventDefault();

        //get the id of the clicked link (which is equal to classes of our content
        var filter = $(this).attr('id');

        //show all the list items (this is needed to get the hidden ones shown)
        $('#content ul li').show();

        /*using the :not attribute and the filter class in it we are selecting
        only the list items that don't have that class and hide them '*/
        $('#content ul li:not(.' + filter + ')').hide();

    });

});
</script>
```

I need to changed this so that, the jQuery is activated when an option is changed in a DropDownList/SELECT. However, I can't quite get my head around how to change this JScript to detect the selection in the DDL rather than a hyperlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the change() event

```
$("#idOfDropDown").change(function() {
    //code here
    var filter = this.value //gets the value of the selected dropdown item.
});
```

This will fire each time a dropdown selection has been made.